# Inserting 29000 rows via Laravel API in TimescaleDB takes 22min where inserting via Go in Influx1.7 takes 256ms

Tags: php, laravel, go, nginx, timescaledb

I have to insert 29000 rows in 2 DB: TimescaleDB and Influx in my local machine (Ubuntu 20.04 8GB Ram)

When I insert into influx, it is quite fast. I do it with a Golang service that chunk data into piece of 10000 rows, and insert it into influx. it takes 256ms

But to insert into TimescaleDB, it is quite different. First, I use Laravel 8 / PHP8. Maybe not the fastest, but I'm stuck with it.

Then, I insert chunks of 100 row, with `upsert()` function.

This is taking 22min for 29000 rows. I use linux-valet, which use nginx server, php8, and postgres / timescaleDB 12.

I tried to replicate my production settings, in my .env, I have set

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
```

And I executed `php artisan optimize`

It still takes 22 min.

In production, I don't have this issue, because I only insert 5648 rows, and it takes 123 ms for inlux, and 1sec for TimescaleDB. The only difference I guess is that in production, I still run `PHP7.4`

For both local and production, the timescaleDB config is the default one.

I understand Laravel is slow for bulk insert and that Go is much faster for this task.

Why is there such a difference and what should I do to make it quicker ?

EDIT: Added the piece of Laravel Code to insert in TimescaleDB:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
        $body = $request->getContent();
        $meter = json_decode($body, true);
        $chunkSize = 100;
        $measures = $meter['Measures'];
        $chunkedRaws = collect($measures)->chunk($chunkSize);
        $ok = 0;
        $nok = 0;
        foreach ($chunkedRaws as $raws) {
            $raws = $raws->map(function ($raw) use ($meter) {
                if (!isset($raw['s'])) {
                    $source = "Pamela";
                } else {
                    $source = $raw['s'];
                }
                return new \App\Models\Raw([
                    'operation_id' => $meter['OperationID'],
                    'meter_id' => $meter['ID'],
                    'conso_prod' => $meter['ConsoProd'],
                    'timestep' => $meter['Timestep'],
                    'unit' => $meter['Unit'],
                    'source' => $source,
                    'time' => Carbon::parse($raw['t'])->toIso8601ZuluString(),
                    'delta' => $raw['d'],
                ]);
            })->toArray();
            try {
                DB::disableQueryLog();
                $raws = collect($raws)->unique(function ($item) { // eliminate duplicates
                    return $item['time'] . $item['operation_id'] . $item['meter_id'] . $item['conso_prod'];
                })->toArray();
                DB::table('raws')->upsert($raws, ['time', 'operation_id', 'meter_id', 'conso_prod'], ['delta']);
//                DB::table('raws')->insert($raws);
                $ok += $chunkSize;
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                $nok += $chunkSize;
                Log::warning($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        return response()->json(['message' => $ok . " Raws has been inserted,\n " . $nok . " Failed"], 200);
    }
```

Comment: Why chunks of 100 and not 10000? There is any code you can share to us? Maybe there is something that could be improved.

Comment: When I coded it, I saw no difference between chunks of 100, and chunks of 1000. Yes, I can show you the code, but there is also a lot of place where I could make changes that could eventually have more impact than code: Timescale config, Nginx config, PHP config, Laravel config, etc. I will show you the code anyway ! Maybe there is something I can optimize here also!

Comment: It looks fine to me. I don't think I can help you much. What I would do in your situation is to `echo time()` along your code (before and after `->map`, before and after `->unique`, before and after `->upsert`)  and check which step is taking the longest time, and if it's almost the same for every chunk, to isolate the problem. Laravel and Nginx are probably not a part of issue. The chances are better in timescale config, db driver issue, network or database machine limitation (ram/disk).

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that most of the performance is in your use of Laravel (and upserts), which makes the comparison very apples-to-oranges.

If you look at bulk inserts using a standard benchmarking tool (TSBS), you'll see that Timescale outperforms Influx, significantly when your cardinality is higher:

- https://blog.timescale.com/blog/timescaledb-vs-influxdb-for-time-series-data-timescale-influx-sql-nosql-36489299877/
- https://github.com/timescale/tsbs

Curious: why are you stuck with Laravel 8 / PHP8 for TimescaleDB, but can use a Go runner for InfluxDB?

That said, a few suggestions:

- Even when using php, one suggestion is that you benchmark the actual insert performance, as opposed to the overhead of php marshalling (which can be significant.  One way to do that is to wrap the actual insert/SQL call in a timer, while not actually putting your ORM marshalling in that loop.  That at least helps you better understand if the bottleneck is TimescaleDB vs. Laravel.
- Try doing the same as an insert, vs. an UPSERT.
- Less familiar with Laravel myself, but make sure you are using a DB connection pool across inserts, so the ORM isn't establishing a new connection for each insert.  I'm guess

Comment: What do you mean by "makes the comparison very apple-to-orange" ? Stuck with Laravel because this is the stack we use. We are migrating from Influx/Go to Timescale/Php. I could code a specific service in Go for inserting into Timescale, but it would take me some a time I don't have right now.

Comment: After measuring time for each of my code, I can say that this is the $raws->map() that is taking 60 sec. If I split 29000 into 60, I'll get 29 minutes, which is approx what I get. I'll see how I can optimize the map function

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mike that this is more apples-to-oranges for a number of reasons. From your description, it "feels" like there must be some kind of blocking going on with the transactions, really outside of TimescaleDB. I also don't have experience with Laravel, but I'm certain TimescaleDB/Postgres isn't your issue at this scale. I've recently been doing lots of ingest benchmarking with TimescaleDB using TSBS (written in Golang) and even on a 2vCPU/8GB instance, I consistently achieve 75K-85K rows/second on a table that has 10 values (columns), batched at 10,000 rows, using 24 "workers" (connections)

I assume you're using the `laravel-upsert` plugin (https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-upsert) which appears to convert your queries to `INSERT INTO... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET...`. While this in and of itself isn't a specific issue (generally), you could easily get multiple connections/transactions attempting to select and then update rows in the same page (taking exclusive locks), causing blocking, and duking it out. This can be a particular problem if you have no time order to your data and multiple batches executing at once (multiple threads/connections).

Do you see any evidence of something like that in your Postgres logs?

Comment: I was using laravel-upsert, but then it has been coded inside laravel, so now, using built-in laravel fonction. Still doing the same ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE. I'm not seeing anything in postgres log :(

Comment: OK. Sounds like you found the issue with the map function. Pretty crazy that it would take that long!